# Writing listview contents to html file android

Tags: android, html, listview, export

I have a listview that is being filled from my database. Now I want to take the contents of this listview and show it in html table.

How I can take my listview and write its contents to html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did something very similar here.

```
 private File saveResults() {
    /*
     * Write the results to a file.
     */
    List<RiderResult> Results = DataModel.get().getResults();

    try {
        if (!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
            Toast.makeText(SummaryFragment.this.getContext(), "Unable to access external storage.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return null;
        }

        /*
         * Create a file folder in external storage.
         */
        File csvDir = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "Android/data/ca.mydomain.myapp/results");
        if (!csvDir.exists())
            csvDir.mkdirs();

        /*
         * Create a file in the folder, with today's date and time as the name.
         */
        Date dateNow = new Date ();
        SimpleDateFormat dateformatYYYYMMDD = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm");
        StringBuilder nowMMDDYYYY = new StringBuilder( dateformatYYYYMMDD.format( dateNow ) );

        File csvFile = new File(csvDir, "result_" + nowMMDDYYYY + ".csv");

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(csvFile, false));

        /*
         * Write a header row.
         */
        bw.write("Finish Seq, Start Num,Clock Time, Actual Time\n");

        /*
         * and a row for each result, comma separated
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < Results.size(); i++) {
            String row = new String();
            row = "" + (i + 1) + "," + Results.get(i).getStartNo()
                    + "," + Results.get(i).getClockTimeString() + ","
                    + Results.get(i).getActualTimeString() +"\n";
            bw.write(row);
        }

        bw.close();



        /*
         *  Return the File to the user - for use in a message or email attachment.
         */
        return csvFile;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I was writing to a file which I later attach to an email or send via BlueTooth, or just leave it on file. My file is CSV (race results) and the name of the file is generated. But you can adapt for your use.

Comment: Thanks, but what does DataModel stands for in List<RiderResult> Results = DataModel.get().getResults();

Comment: DataModel in my case is a singleton where I track the state of my tabs and collect results. But you will have a different source for your data: your database.
I only intended for my code to help with the creation and writing of a file.
I should also mention that my manifest had to request permission to write to the SD card.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I was just wondering if it will have any use for me.

Comment: I think the DataModel was very specific to my case. I have three different tabs taking my app through its states and collecting data. My Main Activity observes and co-ordinates. The logic to write to file was in the fourth, final tab Fragment. 
 From what I understand, you already have the HTML you want to output so I don't think you will have need for anything similar to my DataModel.